# GGPlotly change tooltip hover position

Tags: r, plotly, visualization, ggplotly

I'm wondering if there's a way to force the tooltip to hover on the opposite of a bar graph. For example, in the following plot, the cursor can cover the tooltip in the top 2 bars, but not the bottom bar. I'm wishing to coerce the tooltip to hover on the dictated side of the end of the bargraph:

[image: tooltip is to the left of the end of the bar]

[image: tooltip is to the right of the bar]

I'd like to dictate which side of the end of the bargraph the tooltip sits.
Code to reproduce plots:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

iris_grouped <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise("Mean.petal.length" = mean(Petal.Length))

plot <- ggplot(data = iris_grouped, aes(x = Species, y = Mean.petal.length))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+
  coord_flip()

ggplotly(p = plot)
```

Comment: You can set the xaxis range so that all tips open to the outside: `layout(xaxis = list(range = list(0, 10)))`. For more control, you could also use [Dash's `dcc.Tooltip`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tooltip). (`dcc.Tooltip` has an argument called `direction`.)